# Python: OpenCV: Creating an image carousel

Tags: python, opencv

I have 5 images, namely im1, im2, im3, im4 and im5 which are all in JPG format.
I want to create an image carousel using these images.
I've started with the following code:

```
from time import sleep
import cv2
imagelist = ["im1.jpg", "im2.jpg", "im3.jpg", "im4.jpg", "im5.jpg"]
for image in imagelist:
   img = cv2.imread(image, 1)
   cv2.namedWindow("SCREEN")
   cv2.imshow("SCREEN", img)
   sleep(0.2)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Problem: It actually creates a cv2 window every 0.2 seconds and
> displays the image. But I want it to display the image in the same
> opened window without closing and creating multiple windows.

Kindly help me doing this task.

Thank you

Comment: I suspect that you need cv2.waitKey(..)  in place of sleep().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sleep, you need to use cv2.waitKey(). I tested it and this should work fine.

waitKey function takes an int for delay in ms but it also records a keypress as an ordinal which you can then use to set up keypress commands eg, quit when pressing q. If you leave it empty it advances a step with any keypress.

I just used glob to grab all the .jpg in the folder but replacing it with the images manually in a list like you did will work fine.

```
import cv2
import glob

imagelist = glob.glob("*.jpg")
for image in imagelist:
   img = cv2.imread(image)
   cv2.imshow("SCREEN", img)
   cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you. You've made my job done easily